# Do not get repeater field post id in Acf

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have implemented a gallery in a repeater field. Every time when I update or insert a new data in a repeater field from the admin a new row is created in the 'wp_posts' table. I need a details page too for each gallery, where more images will be shown. I do not get the post id for each repeated gallery. If I get that the problem will be solved.

My coding as follows..

```
<?php 
  $content_group = get_field('content_group');

  if( have_rows('content_group') ): 

    $i = 1;
    $numrows = count( get_field( 'content_group' ) );
    while( have_rows('content_group') ): the_row(); 

    ?>

    <?php                               
      $images = get_sub_field('gallery');
      if(!empty($images) && isset($images)){
        foreach($images as $img){
    ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $img['sizes']['thumbnail'];?>" alt="" />

      <?php
        } 
      ?>

    <a class="clickherebt" href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/all-details/?id="><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> Click here to view photos from event</a>
    // Want to pass post id within the link

    <?php
      }
    ?>

<?php endwhile;
  endif; 
?>
```

Comment: Are you adding the post ID in the repreater? Can you show us how the Repeater is set up in ACF? A screen grab would help.

Comment: Sure.. this is the screen link
http://www.ogmaconceptions.com/demo/find_my_trainer/screen.png

Comment: The Gallery field only returns information about the images, and I don't see any page in your repeater. What page do you want the gallery to link to? Have you created pages for each of the galleries to link to? If so, you will need to add another field to the repeater to choose the associated page.

Comment: I need to pass the post id with that page too.

Comment: *What* page? You don't mention anything about pages in your code or repeater.

Comment: Ok.. I will add. But what will be the field type for the new repeater for adding the page.

Comment: I don't know, you haven't told us what pages you're talking about! Have you created separate pages for each gallery? If you are linking to existing pages, then you can use either **Page Link** which will return the full URL (so you don't need to build it in your code), or **Page Object** if you want to use the ID.